# How to remove null value legend values in pie chart in RDLC

Tags: rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

How to remove null value legend values in pie chart in RDLC. I have set an expression in the visibility property.

```
=IIf(Fields!grp.Value = "", True, False)
```

But it is not working. But grp value is null in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually dealing with `null`, you should try the following expression:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!grp.Value), True, False)
```

For an empty string you could also try this:

```
=IIf(Len(Fields!grp.Value) = 0, True, False)
```